# searching map by value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have 2 elements (for now) map:

```
#define IDI_OBJECT_5001 5001
#define IDI_OBJECT_5002 5002
    /.../


ResourcesMap[IDI_OBJECT_5001] = "path_to_png_file1";
ResourcesMap[IDI_OBJECT_5002] = "path_to_png_file2";
```

I'm trying to implement method for searching this map. I'm passing string argument (file path) and method return int (key value of map)

```
int ResFiles::findResForBrew(string filePath)
{
string value = filePath;
int key = -1;
for (it = ResourcesMap.begin(); it != ResourcesMap.end(); ++it)
{
    if (/*checking if it->second == value */)
    {
        key = it->first;
        break;
    }
}
return key;
}
```

class ResFiles
{
        public:
    ResFiles();
    ~ResFiles();

```
map <int, string> ResourcesMap;
map <int, string>::const_iterator it;
void filenamesForBrew();
int findResForBrew(string filePath);

    private:
```

};

How I could check when it->second-> == value, and then return that key?
I would be grateful for some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem with `it->second == value`?

Comment: You already have it, just do `if (it->second == filePath) return it->first;`.

Comment: I already tried, and visual mark me an error:
"error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: You need to show more code. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Show _the actual code_ that gives the error

Comment: post the `ResourcesMap` declaration

Comment: I have posted declaration, maybe it's something with types?

Comment: OK, next question is: what compiler?? `it->second == value` **must** work just fine if your compiler is worth anything

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic implementation

```
 template <typename K, typename V>
     K keyFor(std::map<K, V> const& map, V const& target)
     {
         for (typename std::map<K, V>::const_iterator it=map.begin(); it!=map.end(); ++it)
             if (it->second == target)
                return it->first;

         return K(); // or throw?
     }
```

Or, with C++11 support:

```
         for (auto& pair : map)
             if (pair.second == target)
                return pair.first;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing should work, (just `it->second ==value` ) although if you want an "efficient" look up value to key, you should create a second map.

There are algorithms such as `std::find` which would need a special predicate but they just use a loop underneath and would be no more efficient, as the search is still linear.

If you want to do this a lot (question your design if you are...) and want a special template you could either:

```
template< typename K, typename V >
bool findByValue( std::map<K,V> const& theMap, K& key, const V& value )
{
    typename std::map<K,V>::const_iterator iter;
    for( iter it = theMap.begin(), itEnd = theMap.end(); it != itEnd; ++it )
    {
        if( it->second == value )
        {
            key = iter->first;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively a custom predicate for std::find_if

```
template< typename P > 
class Match2nd
{
   typedef typename P::second_type value_type;
   value_type val;

  public:

   explicit Match2nd( value_type const& v ) : val( v )
   {
   }

   bool operator()( P const& p ) const
   {
      return p.second == val;
   }
};

template< typename M > 
Match2nd< typename M::value_type >
makeMatch2nd( const M& map, typename M::mapped_type const& v )
{
    return Match2nd< M::value_type >( v );
}
```

then in your code you can:

```
std::map< int, std::string >::const_iterator iter =
  std::find_if( ResourcesMap.begin(), ResourcesMap.end(), makeMatch2nd( value ) );

// if iter is end() the key doesn't exist, 
//if it does then iter->first is your key
```

you could put that into a function of course..

With C++0x you can also put the Match2nd into a lambda and put into std::find. However...

All this stuff is still linear search. If your map is large, put in a map the other way or boost::multi_index or similar.

Comment: thanks for a clue about 2 maps algoritm. My map is small for now, but it will be quite large, and I concider  non lineral searching.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it:

```
int ResFiles::findResForBrew(string filePath)
{
string value = filePath;
int key = -1;
for (it = ResourcesMap.begin(); it != ResourcesMap.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it->second.compare(filePath) == 0)
    {
        key = it->first;
        break;
    }
}
return key;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why `it->second == value` failed to compile though. Just out of curiosity, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 12 for C/C++

Comment: I have *.c and *.cpp files in my project. It may affect for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your Key is the path, why index by ID?

If you will look by the file path, use it as Key, it would be faster than iterate for each key of the map looking for a certain value.

Second one, IMHO I advise to use const values instead of `#define`s, the `#define`s haven't type so it can be troublesome if is performed some unexpected data conversion, I'm a big fan of the strong value types.

Try this:

```
// The type of the ID of the Resources.
typedef int ObjectID;

// Current resources.
const ObjectID IDI_OBJECT_5001 = 5001;
const ObjectID IDI_OBJECT_5002 = 5002;

// The type of a map containing resources, you can assure that 
// a Resource ID would be stored, as you can see at the mapped type.
typedef std::map<const std::string, const ObjectID> idpath;

idpath ResourcesMap;
```

Third, I discourage the use of the `map::operator[]` to insert values, calling this operator you're creating an *empty* object and then, assigning the new value via the `operator=` of the mapped type; not to mention that if the object already exists, is overwritted. So, using this operator i think that you're doing more operations than using the `map::insert` method:

```
ResourcesMap.insert(idpath::value_type("path_to_png_file1", IDI_OBJECT_5001));
ResourcesMap.insert(idpath::value_type("path_to_png_file2", IDI_OBJECT_5002));
```

So, finally, what to do in your code:

```
const ObjectID ID_NULL = 0;

ObjectID ResFiles::findResForBrew(string filePath) const // note the const ;)
{
    ObjectID Result = ID_NULL;
    // Perform the built-in map find, better than iterate the whole map.
    idpath::const_iterator Found = ResourcesMap.find(filePath);

    if (Found != ResourcesMap.end())
    {
        Result = Found->second;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Remember, this algorithm assuming that you can swap your Key-Map pair, if you don't, you need to iterate the whole map.

Comment: I know using #define is quite dangerous in future, but I can't change that. It's a part of creating resources in BREW developing. My mechanism with filepath is to adapt another project written in JAVA to BREW technology. It's some kind of simulation that resources are loaded from filepath.